# More than 2 notebooks with R code in zeppelin failing with error sparkr intrepreter not responding

Tags: apache-zeppelin, sparkr

I have met with a strange issue in running R notebooks in zeppelin(0.7.2).
Spark intrepreter is in per note Scoped mode and spark version is 1.6.2 and SPARK_HOME is set.

Please find the steps below to reproduce the issue:

1. Create a notebook (Note1) and run any r code in a paragraph. I ran the following code.

   ```
   %r
   rdf <- data.frame(c(1,2,3,4))
   colnames(rdf) <- c("myCol")
   sdf <- createDataFrame(sqlContext, rdf)  
   withColumn(sdf, "newCol", sdf$myCol * 2.0)
   ```
2. Create another notebook (Note2) and run any r code in a paragraph. I ran the same code as above.

Till now everything works fine.

3. Create third notebook (Note3) and run any r code in a paragraph. I ran the same code. This notebook fails with the error

> org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.InterpreterException: sparkr is not
>   responding

What I understood from the analysis is that  the process created for sparkr interpreter is not getting killed properly and this makes every third model to throw an error while executing. The process will be killed on restarting the sparkr interpreter and another 2 models could be executed successfully. ie, For every third model run using the sparkr interpreter, the error is thrown.

Help me to fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

you need to set spark.r.numRBackendThreads larger than 2. By default it is 2 which means you can only have 2 threads for RBackend. Since you are using scoped mode per note, each note will consume one thread for RBackend, so you can only run 2 note.